# Connect iPhone App To Server App On Computer

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I was wondering if someone could provide me with a tutorial or other information on how to connect an iPhone app to a server app that runs on a computer. This would be similar to VNC apps that connect to a server to control a computer.

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. Did you find an answer to this? How would you go about streaming your mac screen to your iPhone/iPad?

Comment: Sorry, never did manage to find an answer. Good luck in your searches!

Answer (score 0):

That depends to what the actual server is, depending on what you want to do, you could expose the Server functionality you want to access as a Web Service, or use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

Comment: As a simple app, I am just looking to communicate keyboard presses to the computer.